# session id is changing after every request

Tags: php, angular, session-cookies

I have a php backend for API's and I am using Angular5 for my frontend. I was wondering, how can I handle sessions on Angular? I tried reading the documentation and was unable to come up with anything.

After login if I am making any request it is creating different session id?

Comment: Do you mean different session_id in `PHP`?

Comment: yes..I am getting different PHPSESSID in every request I am making after login..I am new to angular 5.Please help

Answer (score 0):

for the frontend, if you want to access the values from the browser and send it to sever as well try storing the values in local storage which are very simple to set as well as to get in angular.

just you need to write is

```
localStorage.setItem('yourstoragename', JSON.stringify({ token: token, name: name }));
```

to access this you can write as

```
var name = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('yourstoragename'));
console.log(name);
```

Comment: I am not getting any token from backend , I am getting only userinfo in json format.So , then how I will maintain the seesion

Comment: at the time of login when you are getting this userinfo json format just add that json format in localstorage by set it like localStorage.setItem('userinfo',userinfo);and every time you can access this by using getItem('userinfo');

Answer (score 0):

Session data is something handled by the server-side, and the client (Angular in your case) is not able to read it. 
The client (Browser for example) can get the session_id, and store additional information to be kept (Not secured information, as you can see all cookies's data with DevTools for example).

In most cases, after post of the login, the server will give you a token that you can use with later requests, so on your side you have to keep that token, and use it with the following requests to the PHP Server.

Refs:

https://coderwall.com/p/8wrxfw/goodbye-php-sessions-hello-json-web-tokens

Comment: I am not getting any token from backend , I am getting only userinfo in json format at the time o f login.So , then how I will maintain the seesion. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use $_SESSION in my PHP to handle user login with ionic-angular-3.9.2. Using {withCredentials: true} in the Angular HttpClient requests was the part I had a hard time finding. I posted a detailed answer in my reply to this question (other solutions are there also):[Why session PHP can’t be used with Ionic?](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/why-session-php-cant-be-used-with-ionic/1033330)